# PHP Header() not working for Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, simple-html-dom

I am attempting to parse a file downloads page, and then depending upon what arguement was passed in the URL, redirect them to the appropriate download file automatically. Everything works fine when I echo it, but when I attempt to use header() it does nothing.

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
//echo $dom->loadHTML($html) ? "success<br/>" : "failed<br/>";
libxml_clear_errors();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$version = $_GET['version'];

if($version == "beta")
{
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element)
    {
        if($element->getAttribute('class') == "downloadButton chan-rb  mini")
        {
            foreach ($element->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
            {
                if( $link->getAttribute('class') == "tooltipd")
                {
                    $lnk = $link->getAttribute('href')."<br/>";
                    $url = "Location:http://dl.bukkit.org".$lnk;
                    header($url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I believe I am running into the issue of the Headers already being sent, although I am not using any HTML prior to this. Are there any good alternatives that work for redirecting to an actual file (in this case they are .jar extensions).

Comment: Not using html doesn't mean much. It's **ANY** output, of any sort, which can include php warnings and the like. The instant a single byte of output is sent, whether you did or PHP did it, you'll get the 'headers already sent' warnings.

Comment: Why is the a `<br />` in your `Location` header?

Comment: Woops, that was left over from earlier, good catch. And thank you for the explanation Marc B. What can I use as an alternative?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but there's [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Basically my code is going to parse a website and find a link such as http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/get/00790_1.1-R6/craftbukkit.jar which I need to automatically redirect to that link to start the download.

Comment: Perhaps you saved your file as UTF-8 with BOM? That BOM occurs at the beginning of the document, and is included in the output.Check with something like Notepad++. Of course, this applies for the included file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by removing all the lines it said were sending the Header information early. Here is the code, but if anyone has any suggestions on speeding this up (it is fairly slow) please let me know!

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$version = $_GET['version'];

if($version == "beta")
{
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element)
    {
        if($element->getAttribute('class') == "downloadButton chan-beta  mini")
        {
            foreach ($element->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
            {
                if( $link->getAttribute('class') == "tooltipd")
                {
                    $url = "Location:http://dl.bukkit.org".$link->getAttribute('href');
                    header($url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brett, consider that depsite sending the `header($url)` and redirecting a users browser your script will still be running until it's reached a logical conclusion, in this case until it has reached the end of your `foreach` loop. Add `break;` after you send the header(). This may not improve the speed of the script but will reduce load on your server once a user has been redirected.